# Python Code: Once QIV Is Launched, Code Pauses

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I have a question regarding my Python code.  It seems that once I start QIV using `os.system`, the code stops.  This is proved by my code below.  Once the code is ran and I press the button on GPIO 17, the "Hello" is not printed into the terminal.  Only after I close QIV, it prints it.  There is not much else to say, thank you for reading this!  If you need any more information, please tell me.

Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def slideShow(channel):
    os.system("sudo qiv -w 100 *.jpg")
    print("Hello")

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback = slideShow, bouncetime = 2000)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def kill(channel):
    os.system("sudo pkill qiv")
    print("Hello")

GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback = kill, bouncetime = 2000)

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Error: Unable to read file: Failed to open file '*.jpg': No such file or directory.

Comment: if you don't want your call to qiv to block you should use psopen instead of os.system as described in this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636561/how-can-i-run-an-external-command-asynchronously-from-python

Comment: try escaping the *

Comment: @SteveRobillard Sorry, what I just told you was wrong.  The problem is that it cannot recognize the files in the folder anymore.

Comment: @MadMike I put the error up.

Comment: As the error says, `qiv` can't find any find any jpg Files. Check if the files are there and if you are running your script from the right directory.

Comment: @MadMike I am sure, when I change the * to the file name, it works.

Comment: Apparently `os.system` doesn't open a shell and thus doesn't support [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) you really need move to `subprocess.Popen` like in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997048/python-subprocess-wildcard-usage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Switch away from `os.system(...)` to `subprocess.popen(...)`

The way you wan't to use `os.system(...)` has two crucial problems:

1. It won't return until the command has was finished.
2. It doesn't open a shell and thus won't expand `*.jpg` to the available files ending with `jpg` in your current directory.

Both and those problems can be solved by using `subprocess.popen(...)` as in:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('qiv -w 100 *.jpg', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

### Find a solution that doesn't need root-privileges

Check if you *really* need root rights. Make an effort to change your system so you don't.

If there is a error within your script, the same script with root-rights might be a leverage to give a hacker an entry point to your whole system.

If you still need root rights, use it only for the parts of the script that [really needs it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190571/sudo-in-non-interactive-script).

Comment: The part about `sudo` is not entirely true: the OP may be better off without `sudo`, but for different reasons. `sudo` is smart enough to detect a non-interactive call (plus there's a `-n` switch if you want to be sure). And running the whole script as root makes thinks even worse from security perspective.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev  Thanks for the input. I've changed that part. I'm open for more improvements.